Encountering Error (Unhandled Runtime Error) When Utilizing Component with Dynamic API Calls: How to Resolve? (NextJS)
I am new to web development and am currently building a web app that utilizes the IGDB API (https://www.igdb.com). Essentially, it's a website where users can listen to game soundtracks and guess which game they belong to.
To select a game, I have an input field for the user to type the game name. This input should dynamically trigger the corresponding API call to retrieve the game data. I have tried using the API with hardcoded searches, and it works. However, when I create a 'use client' component to monitor the input state and make API calls based on that, it doesn't work, and I receive this error:

This is the code of the page:
The page that uses "use client":
"use client";
import { useState } from "react"; // Import useState hook from React for state management
import { TunePlayer } from "@/components/ui/audio-player/tune-player"; // Import TunePlayer component for playing tunes
import Search from "@/components/ui/game-ui/search"; // Import Search component for searching games
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"; // Import Input component for receiving user input

export default function Tune() {
  // State to hold the search term
  const [searchGame, setSearchGame] = useState({
    name: "Kingdom Hearts", // Initial state with a default search term
  });

  // Function to update the search term based on user input
  const handleSearchChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchGame({ name: event.target.value }); // Update state with new search term
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Audio player component to play game tunes */}
      <TunePlayer />
      <div className="flex  place-content-center place-items-center lg:flex-row gap-8 sm:gap-6  m-auto max-w-80">
        {/* Search input field for entering game search terms */}
        <Input
          type="search"
          placeholder="search your game"
          onChange={handleSearchChange} // Trigger handleSearchChange on input change
        />
      </div>
      <div className="outline-8 outline-white justify-items-center grid gap-3 p-6">
        {/* Displaying the current search term */}
        <p>Searching for {searchGame.name}</p>
        {/* Search component with search parameters passed as props */}
        <Search searchParams={searchGame} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

The search component:
import Link from "next/link";
import CustomImage from "@/components/ui/game-ui/custom-image";
import api from "@/api/igdb";

export default async function Search({ searchParams }: any) {
  // Use the search function from the API with the given search parameters
  const games = await api.search(searchParams);
  console.log(games);

  return (
    <div className="px-4 xl:px-40">
      {/* Check if any games were found */}
      {games.length ? (
        <div className="mt-4 grid grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-6 gap-y-6 gap-x-2">
          {/* Map over the array of games and display each game */}
          {games.map((game: any) => (
            // Use the Link component for navigation. Key is required for list items in React for unique identification.
            <Link key={game.id} href={`/games/${game.id}`}>
              {/* Figure tag used for semantic markup of image (CustomImage) and caption */}
              <figure>
                <div className="relative aspect-[3/4] rounded-xl c-bg-dark-blue transition md:hover:brightness-110">
                  {/* CustomImage component displays the game's image. Props are spread from the game object. */}
                  <CustomImage {...game} />
                </div>

                {/* Figcaption displays the game's name. Text size and margin adjustments for responsive design. */}
                <figcaption className="mt-2.5 text-xs   sm:mt-3 sm:text-base font-bold text-center line-clamp-3">
                  {game.name}
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        // Display a message if no games were found
        <h2 className="mt-4">No games found</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

And the api calls it is using:
import { API_URL, CLIENT_ID, TOKEN_URL } from "@/lib/igdb-config";

interface Token {
  access_token: string; // Token to authenticate API requests.
}

interface RequestParams {
  resource: string; // The endpoint to request data from.
  body: string; // The body of the request, usually containing the query.
}

interface SearchParams {
  name: string; // The name to search for.
  [key: string]: any; // Allows for additional, dynamic parameters.
}

// Query to fetch games by their rating, with various filters applied.
const gamesByRating = `
  fields
    name,
    cover.image_id;
  sort aggregated_rating desc;
  where aggregated_rating_count > 20 & aggregated_rating != null & rating != null & category = 0;
  limit 12;
`;

// Query to fetch detailed information about a single game.
const fullGameInfo = `
  fields
    name,
    summary,
    aggregated_rating,
    cover.image_id,

    genres.name,
    screenshots.image_id,

    release_dates.platform.name,
    release_dates.human,

    involved_companies.developer,
    involved_companies.publisher,
    involved_companies.company.name,

    game_modes.name,
    game_engines.name,
    player_perspectives.name,
    themes.name,

    external_games.category,
    external_games.name,
    external_games.url,

    similar_games.name,
    similar_games.cover.image_id,

    websites.url,
    websites.category,
    websites.trusted
;`;

export const api = {
  token: null as Token | null, // Initially, there's no token.

  // Function to retrieve a new token from the TOKEN_URL.
  async getToken(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(TOKEN_URL, { method: "POST", cache: "no-store" });
      this.token = (await res.json()) as Token; // Parse and store the token.
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error); // Log any errors that occur during the fetch operation.
    }
  },

  // Function to make an authenticated request to the API.
  async request({ resource, ...options }: RequestParams): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.token) {
      throw new Error("Token is not initialized."); // Ensure the token is present.
    }

    const requestHeaders: HeadersInit = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");
    requestHeaders.set("Client-ID", CLIENT_ID);
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${this.token.access_token}`);

    return fetch(`${API_URL}${resource}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: requestHeaders,
      ...options,
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data; // Return the parsed JSON data.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error; // Return any errors that occur during the fetch operation.
      });
  },

  // Function to fetch games by their rating using a predefined query.
  getGamesByRating(): Promise<any> {
    return this.request({
      resource: "/games",
      body: gamesByRating, // Use the gamesByRating query.
    });
  },

  // Function to fetch detailed information about a single game by its ID.
  getGameById(gameId: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.request({
      resource: "/games",
      body: `${fullGameInfo} where id = (${gameId});`, // Use the fullGameInfo query with a specific game ID.
    });
  },

  // Function to search for games based on a name and optional additional fields.
  search({ name = "", ...fields }: SearchParams): Promise<any> {
    let str = ""; // Initialize an empty string for additional search parameters.

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fields)) {
      str += ` & ${key} = ${value}`; // Append each additional field to the search query.
    }

    return this.request({
      resource: "/games",
      body: `
      fields
        name,
        cover.image_id;
      where
        cover.image_id != null
        ${str};
      ${name ? `search "${name}";` : ""}
      limit 50;`, // Construct the final search query.
    });
  },
};

await api.getToken(); // Initialize the token before exporting the API.

export default api;

When removing  the runtime error does not occur. Also when I remove the use client and give it some searchParams manually it does work and the api gets called correctly.

First you need to know that you cannot mark a client component(with "use client" directive) async as you are doing for your Search component. Usage of use client directive on your Tune component automatically makes your Search component a client component since your are importing it directly. From my best guess, the error should likely be something in the line of You cannot make client components async. Anyway you got the idea. It will work if you remove use client directive because now both your Tune and Search component is a server component for which you can make your component async and since you are already providing your search name, the api call is successful and everything is good. Also note that server components are rendered only once i.e. on the server during request time or build time based on whether your page is dynamic or static. Now you have two options to go on about your logic.

Keep the Search component as it is(async) and use searchParams props of your page component. Now whenever the user types in the input field, you update the query string(searchParams) instead of using state, which will cause server request and your page will be rendered with the updated searchParams object which you can pass down to your Tune component and then to your Search component.

You keep the Tune component as it is and modify the Search component to use client side data fetching i.e. fetch data inside useEffect or with other client side data fetching libraries like useSWR or react-query


Extra:

The only way currently to use server component inside client components is via children prop. You accept the server component as a children prop inside client component and render it.
You can use client components inside server component by importing it directly.
It's quite a pain currently while working with search param updates in NextJs app router so checkout this library nuqs which supports shallow updates as well.

Leave a comment if you have any follow up questions.

Thank you a lot for taking the time to explain this!
